# Firefox AddOn - Backbutton Cleanup

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

We just work on a firefox addon which loads several pages via the urlbar.

Unfortunately some entries there don't belong to the backbutton list + we do not want to clutter the backbutton.

So how to prevent Firefox from saving a siteload in the backbutton list? or delete it? history -1?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using loadURI, you can use the `nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_REPLACE_HISTORY` flag to make the new page overwrite the existing history entry rather than creating a new one. If you're setting `content.location`, use `content.location.replace()` instead.